# Apache upgrade from 2.4.6 to 2.4.29

Tags: apache, http, webserver, rhel7

Currently, we are planning to upgrade our complete web-server node in production.
Platform is RHEL 7.1 and currently apache 2.4.6 is running there.

I also got to know from red-hat that apache 2.4.6 is directly shipped with RHEL7 and for 2.4.26 or 2.4.29, they can't comment regarding it's technical feasibility part along with it's stability on RHEL platform.

I have few concerns now :

1. Is going ahead with apache 2.4.26 or 2.4.29 in production would be a good option or should i get stuck with the current one ? I am doubtful whether 2.4.26 or 2.4.29 are been tested on RHEL 7 series and is technically compatible.
2. I tried to install apache 2.4.26 and 2.4.29 on my test-bed first ( which is a RHEL 7.4 platform ) and i came across package dependency issues which proved out to be a blocker for me. I am afraid that i might face these issues on production as well which would be very dangerous. Have you ever faced this on your system too ?

Looking out for your kind support and feedback here ... !!!

Best Regards,

Comment: Why are you exactly upgrading from 2.4.6?

Comment: Actually, customer is insisting us to get this upgraded to the latest version of apache

Comment: You can probably install 2.4.27 from [RED HAT SOFTWARE COLLECTIONS 3.0](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_software_collections/3/html/3.0_release_notes/chap-rhscl#sect-RHSCL-About)

Answer (score 0):

looking at : [httpd direct rpm download](https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/httpd/2.4.6-80.el7/x86_64/fd431d51/package)

it seems that the last supported version is httpd-2.4.6-80.el7.x86_64.rpm

so do not try update your production environment with unsupported software, stick to releases !

upgrading to RHEL7.4 seems to be trouble-maker (as far as i heard : [source required !] )

i got no feedback about RHEL7.5

Comment: Thanks Tassinp for your revert ... !!! But you mentioned about 7.4 as a trouble-maker ... have you come acroos any such situations in your production environment too ?